# Best way for my subquery in django

Tags: python, django, orm

I am quite new in Django ORM, so maybe my problem is trivial. When i create my query like this:

```
mostSaved = models.Rhyme.objects.all().annotate(saved_count=Count('profiles'), vote_strength=Sum('votes__strength')).order_by('-saved_count')[:6]
```

I have wrong result because vote_strengh is counted two times. I dont know how to make subquery in django's ORM. In postgres my correct query should be something like this:

```
SELECT tab.id, SUM("frontsite_voterhyme"."strength") AS "vote_strength" 
FROM(
    SELECT 
    "frontsite_rhyme"."id", "frontsite_rhyme"."title", "frontsite_rhyme"."content",    "frontsite_rhyme"."created", "frontsite_rhyme"."author_id", "frontsite_rhyme"."category_id", 

    COUNT("frontsite_rhyme_profiles"."userprofile_id") AS "saved_count" 
    FROM "frontsite_rhyme" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "frontsite_rhyme_profiles" ON ( "frontsite_rhyme"."id" = "frontsite_rhyme_profiles"."rhyme_id" ) 
    GROUP BY "frontsite_rhyme"."id", "frontsite_rhyme"."title", "frontsite_rhyme"."content", "frontsite_rhyme"."created", "frontsite_rhyme"."author_id", "frontsite_rhyme"."category_id" 
    ORDER BY "saved_count" 
    DESC LIMIT 6
)tab
LEFT OUTER JOIN "frontsite_voterhyme" ON ( tab."id" = "frontsite_voterhyme"."rhyme_id" ) 
GROUP BY tab.id
```

What is best way to do it in ORM in Django

Comment: you can execute raw SQL in Django, YourModel.objects.raw(SQL) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 0):

There's a `distinct` argument that you can use on `Count`. It's undocumented so it may change in the future without a notice in the release changes.

```
mostSaved = models.Rhyme.objects.all().annotate(
    saved_count=Count('profiles', distinct=True),
    vote_strength=Sum('votes__strength')
).order_by('-saved_count')[:6]
```